# How to recreate this CYK parse table

Tags: tikz-pgf, parsing

I would like to use something that looks like the following table in my document, but I have no idea of how to make this using TikZ or other packages. Using a matrix leaves too much empty space above in my tries.

The cells should be editable, so I can show the parsing steps.

[image]

Comment: If you tried something, please help us help you and show what you got so far. It is much easier to help you by extending a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that you provide than to come up with something that might be completely different from what you want to do. What do you mean with "editable"? Do you need some kind of interactive PDF or do you just want to fill the cells in via entering something in the code?

Comment: This is not a "do it for me" site. Provide an MWE that we can compile showing what you tried and what the problem is.

Comment: @PeterWilson sadly, it has been a while since I tried doing this and I have deleted the associated files.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Regarding the MWE, see above. With editable, I meant to say that I would like to write something into the cells in the document code, not an editable PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a `\pic`, but since you did not say how you want to use this, I don't know whether such an approach would suit your needs:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{tiltedmatrixcolumncount}
\tikzset{
    tilted matrix/reset columns/.code={
        \setcounter{tiltedmatrixcolumncount}{0}
    },
    tilted matrix/column head/.code={
        \stepcounter{tiltedmatrixcolumncount}
        \tikzset{tilted matrix/column head \arabic{tiltedmatrixcolumncount}/.initial={#1}}
    },
    tilted matrix/header nodes/.style={
        anchor=base,
    },
    pics/tilted matrix/.style={
        /tikz/tilted matrix/reset columns,
        /tikz/tilted matrix/column head/.list={#1},
        code={
            \draw (0.5,0) -- ++(0,-0.5) coordinate (-coord 0-0); 
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] 
                in {1,...,\arabic{tiltedmatrixcolumncount}} {
                \node[tilted matrix/header nodes] at (\x,0.25) 
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tilted matrix/column head \x}};
                \draw ({\x + 0.5},0) -- ++(0,-0.5) coordinate (-coord \x-0)
                    -- ++({\x * -0.5},{\x * -0.5});                
                \ifnum\value{tiltedmatrixcolumncount}<2\else
                    \foreach \i [count=\y] in {\x,...,\arabic{tiltedmatrixcolumncount}} {
                        \coordinate (-node \y-\x) 
                            at ({\x + 0.5 * \y - 0.5},{-0.5 * \y});
                    }
                    \foreach \y [remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0)] 
                        in {1,...,\x} {
                        \coordinate (-coord \x-\y) 
                            at ({\x - 0.5 * \y + 0.5},{-0.5 * \y - 0.5}); 
                        \draw (-coord \x-\y) -- (-coord \lastx-\lasty);
                    }
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pic (my matrix) at (0,0) {tilted matrix={$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$}};

    \node at (my matrix-node 1-1) {1};
    \node at (my matrix-node 3-2) {2};

    \pic (my other matrix) at (0,-4) {tilted matrix={$b$, $b$, $a$, $c$, $b$, $c$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The values to the cells are placed using nodes that are anchored to the relevant coordinates provided by the `\pic`. The logic of the numbering of the coordinates is shown below:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!